# Alors que / quand

Tags: conjonctions

Bonjour,

> **Alors qu**'elle était enfant, elle a été adoptée.
>
> **Quand** elle était enfant, elle a été adoptée.

Quelqu'un m'a dit que la deuxième phrase, avec *quand*, est incorrecte et qu'il faut l'imparfait dans les deux parties de la phrase. Pourtant, je vois parfois ce genre de phrases.

D'après vous, est-ce que la deuxième phrase est correcte ?

Answer (score 5):

« Quand elle était enfant, elle était adoptée » sous entend qu'elle aurait été « désadoptée » depuis, ce qui n'est sûrement pas le sens attendu.

La personne qui a prescrit l'imparfait dans la deuxième phrase s'est donc méprise.

La phrase avec « quand » est correcte et idiomatique. « Quand » est une conjonction générique. Elle plus usuelle que la locution conjonctive « alors que » de registre soutenu quand elle ne marque pas une opposition.

C'est le sens qui restreint les temps possibles bien plus que la conjonction :

> ✓ Quand elle était enfant = Quand c'était une enfant. (correct, elle ne l'est plus)

> ✗ Quand elle a été (une) enfant. Impossible, devenir une enfant n'est pas une action ponctuelle.

> ✗ Elle était adoptée. (signifie un état persistant, bien que ce soit effectivement le cas, ça ne convient pas dans la phrase donnée)

> ✓ Elle a été adoptée. (correct, décrit un événement ponctuel)

Comment: Merci. Mais cette personne m'a dit que la phrase _Lorsqu'il **arrivait** à la maison, il **a trébuché**_ était incorrecte. Ma phrase initiale a la même structure, donc elle devrait être incorrecte, non ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas la structure qui compte ici mais le sens: *arriver à la maison* est un événement ponctuel et répétitif si imparfait à trébucher, rien à voir avec *être enfant*.

Comment: D'accord, merci. Mais en fin de compte, la phrase _Lorsqu'il **arrivait** à la maison, il **a trébuché**_ est-elle correcte ou non ? Je veux dire est-elle acceptable ?

Comment: Pas vraiment: *Alors qu'il arrivait à la maison, il a trébuché.*

Comment: *Lorsqu'il arrivait à la maison* signifie *chaque fois qu'il arrivait à la maison* mais *alors qu'il arrivait à la maison* signifie *au moment où il arrivait (cette fois là) à la maison*

Comment: OK, merci ! Je m'en souviendrai. Mais à mon avis, si la phrase _Lorsqu'il **arrivait** à la maison, il **a trébuché**_ n'est pas acceptable, _**Quand** elle **était** enfant, elle **a été** adoptée_ ne devrait pas l'être non plus...

Comment: *Arriver à la maison*, *trébucher* et *être adopté* sont des événements qui ont lieu à un moment précis alors que *être enfant* représente un état. Ces deux types verbaux ne sont pas comparables, mais je me répète...

Comment: *Il est tombé dans la marmite quand il était petit*...

Comment: jlliagre, Non, c'est bien, formulée ainsi, je comprends mieux cette explication. Je ne l'ai pas comprise avant.

Answer (score 3):

La première indique qu'un événement est survenu au cours d'une période.

La seconde indique plus que quelque chose s'appliquait à toute une période.

C'est pour cette raison que la première est plus appropriée dans ce cas, car le moment où elle a été adoptée n'a pas duré toute son enfance. Son adoption est un événement qui a eu lieu durant son enfance.

Ceci-dit, je comprends les deux formes pareillement sans ambiguïté.

Comment: Je recopie la question que j'ai posée à jlliagre.   Merci. Mais cette personne m'a dit que la phrase _Lorsqu'il **arrivait** à la maison, il **a trébuché**_ était incorrecte. Ma phrase initiale a la même structure, donc elle devrait être incorrecte, non ?

Comment: @Oreste La phrase ne me semble pas incorrecte et en tout cas très compréhensible. L'imparfait n'est peut-être pas le meilleur choix car plus souvent appliqué à des actions habituelles :  *Lorsqu'il arrivait à la maison, il trébuchait toujours sur cette pierre*. Le passé simple est plus classique dans ce cas : *Lorsqu'il arriva à la maison, il trébucha*. Cependant si on tient à l'imparfait, **Alors que** semble plus naturel : *Alors qu'il arrivait à la maison, il a trébuché*.

Comment: Merci @XouDo :)