# J'étais / j'ai été / j'avais été si concentrée sur le sujet X que j'ai oublié de vous demander

Tags: verbes, temps-grammatical, passé-composé, imparfait, plus-que-parfait

J'ai écrit à quelqu'un :

> J'**ai été** si concentrée sur le sujet X que j'ai oublié de vous
> demander...

Jlliagre m'a dit qu'il fallait écrire :

> J'**étais** tellement concentrée sur le sujet X que j'en ai oublié de vous
> poser la question.

Quelle est la différence entre ces trois variantes :

> J'**étais** tellement concentrée sur le sujet X que j'en ai oublié de vous
> poser la question.
>
> J'**ai été** tellement concentrée sur le sujet X que j'en ai oublié de
> vous poser la question.
>
> J'**avais été** tellement concentrée sur le sujet X que j'en ai oublié de
> vous poser la question.

Comment: **se** concentrer sur quelque chose, non?

Comment: @Lambie Pas forcément. *Se concentrer sur* et *être concentré sur* sont tous deux valides. TLFi Concentré: *Fortement appliqué à quelque chose, à l'exclusion d'autre chose; dont l'esprit est entièrement accaparé par quelque chose; très attentif.*

Comment: @jlliagre Vaut mieux voir toutes les possibilités: https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/concentrer/17870

Comment: @Lambie Le Larousse liste *être concentré* qui est la forme utilisée par Oreste et qui n'est pas *se concentrer*.

Comment: 2. Fixer son attention sur quelque chose, y être attentif : Se concentrer sur un problème difficile.=être concentrer sur un problème= le même sense

Answer (score 1):

Il ne s'agit pas d'une question de grammaire mais de logique. Aucune de ces phrases n'est incorrecte mais la première est la plus naturelle.

1. Les deux actions sont liées et concurrentes. L'imparfait est utilisé pour signaler une circonstance plus qu'une action ponctuelle :

> J'étais tellement concentrée sur le sujet X que j'en ai oublié de vous poser la question.

2. Les deux actions semblent moins concurrentes. Au moment où j'ai oublié de poser la question, je n'étais plus concentrée sur le sujet, donc la relation de cause à effet est moins évidente :

> J'ai été tellement concentrée sur le sujet X que j'en ai oublié de vous poser la question.

3. Dans la troisième phrase, on s'attend à une concordance des temps :

> J'avais été tellement concentrée sur le sujet X que j'en ai oublié de vous poser la question → que j'en **avais** oublié de vous poser la question.

Comment: _mais de logique_ --- Encore faut-il que je comprenne cette logique... // La 2ème variante, avec _ai été_, je la comprends ainsi : lors de ma conversation avec le vét, la plupart du temps, je pense au sujet X, mais pas tout le temps, par certains moments, j'écoute le vét, et j'oublie alors le sujet X qui m'inquiète tant. Ma traduction n'est pas bonne ? // Et la 3ème : Durant toute la consultation, j'ai pensé au sujet X, puis à la fin, lorsque j'ai commencé à poser des questions, j'ai oublié ce thème. Ce n'est pas correct ?

Comment: Comme je l'ai écrit, aucune des phrases n'est incorrecte. L'imparfait est plus utilisé pour décrire une circonstance alors que le passé composé traduit une action.  Regarde cette page: https://leflepourlescurieux.fr/passe-compose-et-imparfait-de-l-indicatif-la-comparaison-grammaire-b1/

Comment: Merci. Mais justement, là il est écrit : _Nous avons cuisiné **quand** tu te reposais_. Je me souviens, quelqu'un m'avait dit qu'il est incorrect d'employer "quand" dans ce genre de phrases, qu'il faut écrire "alors que". Aussi, quelqu'un m'a dit que "le Fle" contient parfois des erreurs. // Sinon, est-ce que ce que j'ai écrit dans mon premier commentaire est correct ou je me trompe ?

Comment: *Nous avons cuisiné quand tu te reposais* est correct, comme *pendant que tu te reposais* et *alors que tu te reposais*. La dernière forme insiste sur l'aspect reproche.

Comment: J'ai l'impression qu'on utiliserait *quand* plutôt pour une action soudaine au milieu d'une action longue : *On était en train de cuisiner quand tu t'es endormi/ quand tu es arrivé*, plutôt que pour des actions simultanées.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec @XouDo, sa phrase est correcte. Par contre, _Nous avons cuisiné **quand** tu te reposais_ ne l'est pas, il faudrait écrire _Nous avons cuisiné **alors que** tu te reposais_ ou _Nous avons cuisiné **pendant que**tu te reposais_. On pourrait dire _Nous avons cuisiné **quand** tu te reposais_, mais il est préférable de ne pas l'écrire. Du moins c'est ce que quelqu'un m'a expliqué il y a un certain temps. // Cf ton propre commentaire [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46794/alors-que-quand) _Lorsqu'il arrivait à la maison signifie chaque fois..._

Comment: _La dernière forme insiste sur l'aspect reproche_ --- Pas toujours, mais oui, cela pourrait être ambigu. _Alors que_, c'est aussi _pendant que_.

Comment: @XouDo Oui, la phrase _Nous avons cuisiné quand tu te reposais_ est assez bizarre. _Nous étions en train de cuisiner lorsque / quand tu as appelé_ _Alors que nous  étions en train de cuisiner, tu as appelé._ _Tu as appelé quand / lorsque j'ai ouvert le frigo_.

Comment: @Oreste *Nous avons cuisiné quand tu dormais* me semble tout à fait acceptable à l'oral comme à l'écrit comme par exemple : *Je me suis cassé la jambe quand j'étais petit*. Pour le FLE, c'est vrai, il ne faut pas se fier à tout. Je viens de [lire](https://leflepourlescurieux.fr/quand-et-lorsque-deux-marqueurs-temporels-particuliers-grammaire-b1/) *Tu as ri quand il avait raconté son histoire* qui ne me paraît pas terrible.

Comment: _Nous avons cuisiné quand tu dormais_ me semble tout à fait acceptable --- Donc, toutes les chances que c'est vraiment le cas. Moi, je n'ai pas ton intuition, je ne fais que répéter ce qu'une autre personne m'avait dit. Je me souviens, quelqu'un m'a dit que dans ce genre de phrases, il faut employer _alors que_ et non _quand / lorsque_, et une autre personne a dit _Moi, je dis "quand" à l'oral_.